# Excel Interop - Insert Rows & Repeat

Tags: c#, excel

OK so I have this function that works fine at inserting rows and then putting data within those rows.

```
public void inputRowData(string[] data, int rds)
    {
        int bestRow = getRowByRDS(rds);
        string val = getValueOfCell(bestRow, 6);
        if (val == null || val.Equals(""))
        {
            shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length-1);
            string[] formatedData = formatOutput(bestRow, data);
            // transform formated data into string[,]
            string[][] splitedData = formatedData.Select(s => s.Split('\t')).ToArray();
            var colCount = splitedData.Max(r => r.Length);
            var excelData = new string[splitedData.Length, colCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < splitedData.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < splitedData[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    excelData[i, j] = splitedData[i][j];
                }
            }
            oSheet.get_Range("A" + bestRow.ToString()).Resize[splitedData.Length, colCount].Value = excelData;

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Line has some information already, skipping 1 more");
            shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length + 1);
        }

    }
```

Now I if you take a look i find the "bestRow" which is determined by the last row in the excel with a int value at a particular column the code is show here:

```
private int getRowByRDS(int id)
    {
        int bestfit = -1;
        Boolean foundOne = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range usedRange = oSheet.UsedRange;
        for (int i = 2; i < usedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string val = getValueOfCell(i, 3);
            if (val == null)
                continue;

            int rds = int.Parse(val);
            Console.WriteLine(val + " " +i);
            if (rds == id)
            {
                bestfit = i;
                foundOne = true;
            }
            else
                if (foundOne)
                    return bestfit;
        }
        return bestfit;
    }
```

What happens is that when it finishes on set of data in the inputRowData method it will move to another set with a different rds value. It will try to call getRowByRDS but it will throw an error.

On debug it looks like it didnt update the sheet... so lets say the first set of 10 strings was inserted at row 900, the and if the next set was suppose to start right after it bestRow will return 901 not 911.

The error is

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in TTE Tool.exe
```

Comment: Two questions: **1)** Can you verify that all of the cells are being updated that you expect to?  It is possible that your arrays are not lining up and not all cells are changing.  **2)** If that is OK, my next guess is that this is related to using `UsedRange`.  It is possible (not sure how likely) that this property is not getting updated properly after you change cells.  To test this, use one of the `.End()` methods to get the block of data you are working with.  Or if the data is contiguous (no blanks), use `CurrentRegion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I disposed of the excel beforehand by mistake.